# Azure Service Bus autoscaling in bicep template

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

On our project we are using Service Bus, for the Infrastructure as Code we are using bicep template in order to deploy this Service Bus. Lately we came to the conclusion that we should enable scaling for our service bus as we were having some serious issues with the capacity of just 1 single Message Unit.
Does anyone know if there is anyway to add the autoscaling in the bicep template for a service bus Azure Resource ? I cannot really find something in the MS official documentation.

Google didn't helped ...

Comment: Hi, have you checked Thomas's answer, does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the documentation, there is an ARM template that show how to configure autoscaling:

- [Automatically update messaging units of an Azure Service Bus namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/automate-update-messaging-units#template).

The equivalent bicep (using [az bicep decompile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/bicep?view=azure-cli-latest#az-bicep-decompile)) looks like this:

```
@description('Name of the Service Bus namespace')
param serviceBusNamespaceName string

@description('Name of the Queue')
param serviceBusQueueName string

@description('Name of the auto scale setting.')
param autoScaleSettingName string

@description('Location for all resources.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

resource serviceBusNamespaceName_resource 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2021-11-01' = {
  name: serviceBusNamespaceName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Premium'
  }
  properties: {
  }
}

resource serviceBusNamespaceName_serviceBusQueueName 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues@2021-11-01' = {
  parent: serviceBusNamespaceName_resource
  name: '${serviceBusQueueName}'
  properties: {
    lockDuration: 'PT5M'
    maxSizeInMegabytes: 1024
    requiresDuplicateDetection: false
    requiresSession: false
    defaultMessageTimeToLive: 'P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S'
    deadLetteringOnMessageExpiration: false
    duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow: 'PT10M'
    maxDeliveryCount: 10
    autoDeleteOnIdle: 'P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S'
    enablePartitioning: false
    enableExpress: false
  }
}

resource autoScaleSettingName_resource 'Microsoft.Insights/autoscaleSettings@2021-05-01-preview' = {
  name: autoScaleSettingName
  location: 'East US'
  tags: {
  }
  properties: {
    name: autoScaleSettingName
    enabled: true
    predictiveAutoscalePolicy: {
      scaleMode: 'Disabled'
      scaleLookAheadTime: null
    }
    targetResourceUri: serviceBusNamespaceName_resource.id
    profiles: [
      {
        name: 'Increase messaging units to 2 on weekends'
        capacity: {
          minimum: '2'
          maximum: '2'
          default: '2'
        }
        rules: []
        recurrence: {
          frequency: 'Week'
          schedule: {
            timeZone: 'Eastern Standard Time'
            days: [
              'Saturday'
              'Sunday'
            ]
            hours: [
              6
            ]
            minutes: [
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
      {
        name: '{"name":"Scale Out at 75% CPU and Scale In at 25% CPU","for":"Increase messaging units to 4 on weekends"}'
        capacity: {
          minimum: '1'
          maximum: '8'
          default: '2'
        }
        rules: [
          {
            scaleAction: {
              direction: 'Increase'
              type: 'ServiceAllowedNextValue'
              value: '1'
              cooldown: 'PT5M'
            }
            metricTrigger: {
              metricName: 'NamespaceCpuUsage'
              metricNamespace: 'microsoft.servicebus/namespaces'
              metricResourceUri: serviceBusNamespaceName_resource.id
              operator: 'GreaterThan'
              statistic: 'Average'
              threshold: 75
              timeAggregation: 'Average'
              timeGrain: 'PT1M'
              timeWindow: 'PT10M'
              dimensions: []
              dividePerInstance: false
            }
          }
          {
            scaleAction: {
              direction: 'Decrease'
              type: 'ServiceAllowedNextValue'
              value: '1'
              cooldown: 'PT5M'
            }
            metricTrigger: {
              metricName: 'NamespaceCpuUsage'
              metricNamespace: 'microsoft.servicebus/namespaces'
              metricResourceUri: serviceBusNamespaceName_resource.id
              operator: 'LessThan'
              statistic: 'Average'
              threshold: 25
              timeAggregation: 'Average'
              timeGrain: 'PT1M'
              timeWindow: 'PT10M'
              dimensions: []
              dividePerInstance: false
            }
          }
        ]
        recurrence: {
          frequency: 'Week'
          schedule: {
            timeZone: 'Eastern Standard Time'
            days: [
              'Saturday'
              'Sunday'
            ]
            hours: [
              18
            ]
            minutes: [
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    notifications: []
    targetResourceLocation: 'East US'
  }
}
```